# Spring Boot Application Could not initialize class org.apache.logging.log4j.util.PropertiesUtil

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, gradle

I am trying to implement the hello world web application using spring boot, gradle and tomcat by following ["Building a RESTful Web Service"](https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/) but have been unable to run make it run so far.

The code is pretty much the same as the one provided on the website, I have wasted hours debugging it thinking there was a bug in the provided code but I still can't figure out what's wrong.

I am using Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers, Version: Neon.3 Release (4.6.3), Build id: 20170314-1500

Any idea what could be the issue?

build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:2.0.2.RELEASE")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

bootJar {
    baseName = 'gs-rest-service'
    version =  '0.1.0'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

dependencies {
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
}
```

Greeting.java

```
package App;

public class Greeting {

    private final long id;
    private final String content;

    public Greeting(long id, String content) {
        this.id = id;
        this.content = content;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getContent() {
        return content;
    }
}
```

GreetingController.java

```
package App;

import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicLong;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class GreetingController {

    private static final String template = "Hello, %s!";
    private final AtomicLong counter = new AtomicLong();

    @RequestMapping("/greeting")
    public Greeting greeting(@RequestParam(value="name", defaultValue="World") String name) {
        return new Greeting(counter.incrementAndGet(),
                            String.format(template, name));
    }
}
```

Application.java

```
package App;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.getProperties().put("server.port", 8486);
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

Stacktrace

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.logging.log4j.util.PropertiesUtil
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.status.StatusLogger.<clinit>(StatusLogger.java:71)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.<clinit>(LogManager.java:60)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory$Log4jLog.<clinit>(LogFactory.java:199)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory$Log4jDelegate.createLog(LogFactory.java:166)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:109)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:99)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.<clinit>(SpringApplication.java:198)
    at App.Application.main(Application.java:9)
```

Comment: Do you have anything in your application.properties?

Comment: I don't have a `application.properties` file in my project.

Comment: can you put your project structure on github?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently setting the port number using `System.getProperties().put("server.port", 8486);` the `NoClassDefFoundError` exception.

However creating a `application.properties` file mentioned by @Nitishkumar Singh in the resources folder to specify the port number to use solved the issue.

Answer (score 3):

When using the authorisation manager, this message can also be the result of a missing grant (or file) in the `catalina.policy` or `security.policy` (`-Djava.security.policy`).

For example add:

```
grant codeBase "file:${catalina.base}/webapps/${APPLICATION_NAME}/-" {
    permission java.security.AllPermission;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this dependency:

```
compile group: 'org.apache.logging.log4j', name: 'log4j-core', version: '2.11.0'
```

And try again.

Comment: There is already an transitivity dependecy ```org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web``` -> ```org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter``` -> ```org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging```

Comment: That did not change anything.

Answer (score 0):

Could not initialize class org.apache.logging.log4j.util.PropertiesUtil.
I met the same problem as you. Automated deployment to Tomcat by using Jenkins always occurs. Probably some jar don't exclusion dependecy 'org.apache.logging.log4j'. But springbooot 2.0.1.RELEASE uses logback by default. On org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer:

```
public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
        this.logger = LogFactory.getLog(this.getClass());
        WebApplicationContext rootAppContext = this.createRootApplicationContext(servletContext);
        if (rootAppContext != null) {
            servletContext.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(rootAppContext) {
                public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event) {
                }
            });
        } else {
            this.logger.debug("No ContextLoaderListener registered, as createRootApplicationContext() did not return an application context");
        }

    }

     public static Log getLog(String name) {
        switch(logApi) {
        case LOG4J:
            return LogFactory.Log4jDelegate.createLog(name);
        case SLF4J_LAL:
            return LogFactory.Slf4jDelegate.createLocationAwareLog(name);
        case SLF4J:
            return LogFactory.Slf4jDelegate.createLog(name);
        default:
            return LogFactory.JavaUtilDelegate.createLog(name);
        }
    }
```