# log4j-spring-cloud-client-config causing NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, spring-boot, log4j2

I installed log4j-spring-cloud-client-config so I could do Spring Boot lookup for application properties in my log4j2.xml file.

However, doing so causes this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.logging.log4j.util.PropertiesUtil
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.status.StatusLogger.<clinit>(StatusLogger.java:78)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.Configurator.<clinit>(Configurator.java:43)
    at org.apache.ignite.logger.log4j2.Log4J2Logger$2.apply(Log4J2Logger.java:152)
    at org.apache.ignite.logger.log4j2.Log4J2Logger$2.apply(Log4J2Logger.java:149)
    at org.apache.ignite.logger.log4j2.Log4J2Logger.addConsoleAppenderIfNeeded(Log4J2Logger.java:302)
    at org.apache.ignite.logger.log4j2.Log4J2Logger.<init>(Log4J2Logger.java:149)
    at com.coinflex.service.release.ReleaseApplication.main(ReleaseApplication.java:24)
```

I also have these logging dependencies installed:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.ignite</groupId>
  <artifactId>ignite-log4j2</artifactId>
  <version>2.8.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.pulsar</groupId>
  <artifactId>pulsar-log4j2-appender</artifactId>
  <version>2.6.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: does this related answer help? [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50669888/spring-boot-application-could-not-initialize-class-org-apache-logging-log4j-util)

Comment: What version of log4j-api and log4j-core are you using?

Comment: 2.11.2 are the ones installed

Comment: Please upgrade to Log4j 2.13.3 and try again.